# Explanation of touch event jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, if-statement, touch

I wrote a function that works great for mobile, based on something I found on SO a while ago.

```
    jQuery(document).on('touchstart', function(event) {
        if ( !jQuery(event.target).closest("#peopleMenu").length) {
            jQuery("#peopleMenu").fadeOut();
       } 
    });
```

the part that I found was in the "if" statement that took me a bit to wrap my head around.

It is saying that if the target touch event is on #peopleMenu , it will stay open, or close if touched off. The if statement boils down to :

```
if (!1) {
    //false - understand this.
}

if (!0) {
    //true - hmmm.
}
```

My question is basically is this a common programming paradigm, a strange js feature, or is it just trickier than it needs to be? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is common in many languages. Everything in JavaScript has an inherent Boolean value, generally known as either truthy or falsy.(e.g. 0 or an empty string). So in this case, if the length comes back as 0, the if statement is false. Here is a great writeup on this topic as it relates to Javascript if you care to know more: [Truthy/Falsy](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/)

Answer (score 1):

It is common, it mean if you touch something else than `#peopleMenu` or its childrens, do something.

`0` is a falsy value while every other integer are truthy.

Using bang (`!`) reverse the value, `!true == false` and `!false == true`.

The `.length` property of jQuery is the way to know how many element are selected. 0 mean none.